# Locating SSL certificate, key and CA on server

Tags: node.js, ssl

Disclaimer: you don't need to know `Node` to answer this question but it would help.

I have a Node server and I need to make it work with HTTPS. As I researched around the internet, I found that I have to do something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/ssl/private-key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/ssl/cert'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('path/to/something/called/CA')
};
var app = require('https').createServer(credentials, handler);
```

I have several problems with this. First off, all the examples I found use completely different approaches.

Some link to `.pem` files for both the certificate and `key`. I don't know what `pem` files are but I know my certificate is `.crt` and my key is `.key`. Some start off at the root folder and some seem to just have these `.pem` files in the application directory. I don't.

Some use the `ca` thing too and some don't. This `CA` is supposed to be `my domain's CA bundle` according to some articles - but none explain where to find this file. In the `ssl` directory on my server I have one `.crt` file in the `certs` directory and one `.key` file in the `keys` directory, in addition to an empty `csrs` directory and an `ssl.db` file.

So, where do I find these 3 files (key, cert, ca) and how do I link to them correctly?

Comment: your key is probably a PEM encoded private key. Running `file ssl.key` in linux tells me `PEM RSA private key` so that's one way to test.
otherwise you will probably have to use `openssl rsa` to get your private key with some parameters, see google.

cert will be your .crt file. 

I dont remember where i got my Certification Authority (CA) cert. I think i downloaded it from startcom alongside my key and cert.

Comment: Oh and the paths don't matter but I would place the files in a subdirectory to reduce clutter then point https.createServer at the relevant files. BTW if you want windows paths to work, node can figure out which slashes with `path.join`: `var priv = require('path').join(__dirname, "ssl", "ssl.private.key")`

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the paths, I copied the files to a `ssl` directory on the same level as the `node_servers` directory which contains the server. However, when I point it like `../ssl/certificatefilename.crt` I get an error saying `ENOENT no such file or directory`. Any ideas?

Comment: Same thing happens when I use an absolute path.

Comment: try using `__dirname` like I used in my second comment - `__dirname+"/ssl/certificatefilename.crt"`, __dirname points to the directory where the script is being run. Or `__dirname+"../ssl/certificatefilename.crt"`

Comment: if it fails with an absolute path too... thats weird I would check the spelling and try putting it in the same directory as the server script to see if that works

Comment: When I put it in the same directory, still the same error! I checked spelling (I named it abc.crt just to be sure) and the file name is correct.

Comment: Hm, actually works using `__dirname` and placing the cert in the same directory. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome glad to help! I'm gonna throw a bounty on this question for someone who can explain why the dot notation doesn't properly reference the file and how `__dirname` differs. I bet it will help a lot if you can list your folder and file structure in your answer. *edit:* forgot I cant bounty new questions, sorry :D

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll add the directory structure to the question in the morning, I am very puzzled by this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the difference:

`__dirname` refers to the directory where the script is located in

`.` refers to the location from where you invoked the nodejs command. `..` refers to its parent folder.

Example:

```
cwd > node script.js
```

both `.` and `__dirname` will be same cwd

```
cwd > node /path/to/script.js
```

`.` is `cwd` and `__dirname` is `/path/to`.

Comment: Thanks! @jovan does this tally with your paths?